# How to find owner of queue in rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq

If I see some queue in rabbitmq (f.e. foobar), where is no activity, how I can find who created that queue, or, at least, which channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find out creator except it was declared as exclusive and thus it has only one consumer.

Alternatively, you can find all channels (and thus connections) which utilize specific queue with management plugin.

Comment: If you have a queue naming protocol then you will know by the name of the queue

Comment: @robthewolf, yes, you are right at this point. Without naming convention or any RabbitMQ extensions and other mechanisms like storing that info explicitly, you can't name the exchange or queue creator.